# How to get the The Username of the person that made comment on a Page Post using Facebook Graph API V.6.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried the following url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{commentid}/comments?access_token={pagetoken}
```

The result i got was 3 fields: created_time, message, id.
I need value of "from" field. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you only get a minimum set of fields. You need specify additional fields in the API call:

```
/{commentid}/comments?fields=field1,field2&access_token={pagetoken}
```

Comment: Actually i tried selecting field called "from" but no values is returning.

/{commentid}/comments?fields=from&access_token={pagetoken}